# How to change the value of a cell wiout changing the range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following columns and data:

column1

1(cell A1)
2(A2)

3(A3)

Say I want to do like transpose(A1:A3) but want to change the value of 2 in A2 to 0, "inside the transpose formula". Is this possible??? Thank you very much.

Comment: With VBA, you can read the Value (Range.Value returns a two dimensional array of Variants) in to an array, transpose it, change whatever you want and write it back.

Answer (score 1):

```
{ =TRANSPOSE(A1:A3*(ROW(A1:A3)<>2)) }
```

Some explanation:

We are transposing an array, not directly `A1:A3` but the result of one-by-one multiplication of `A1:A3` and `(ROW(A1:A3)<>2))`. This results in the column vector:

```
A1    *  1                   A1
A2    *  0        =          0
A3    *  1                   A3
```

Which is what you want to transpose.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But what does <>2 mean? I want to change the value of 2 (in cell A2) to 0..

Comment: @JunJang that is what the formula does.

Comment: Jun Jang see added explanations above. Thanks @ScottCraner